# добавить файл в awk также(!) как в bash

Tags: bash, awk

в bash можно написать:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

filename=/home/username/file.txt

$filename
```

и всё имя файла есть можно использовать.

для awk файл добавляется как параметр если вызывается так: `awk 'код скрипта' file.txt`

Если писать код:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
{
   print $0
}
```

Вопрос как подключить файл точно также в коде?

P.S. FILENAME это для файла который указывается как параметр в командной строке

Comment: Точно также, например: `filename="/home/username/file.txt"`.

Comment: Как строка, понятно. А как использовать этот файл внутри кода#!/usr/bin/awk -f
{
   print $0
}

Comment: Попробуйте: `echo 1|awk '{ filename="/home/username/file.txt"; print filename; }'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

практически точно также:

```
$ cat file 
{
  filename="/home/username/file.txt"
  print filename
}
```

запуск:

```
$ echo | awk -f file
/home/username/file.txt
```

---

если же имеется в виду аргумент командной строки, то все они (собственно, как и в программе *bash*), содержатся в массиве. называется массив `ARGV`. элементы в нём пронумерованы от `0` до `ARGC`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{for(i in ARGV){print "аргумент номер",i,"=",ARGV[i]}}' file 
аргумент номер 0 = awk
аргумент номер 1 = file
```